# Graphite Error with MapSeries

Tags: graphite

I get this error with every parameter combination I try for "mapSeries"

Using Graphite v0.9.15

Example url -
http://myGraphite/render/?width=586&height=308&target=mapSeries(server.server1.route.root.admin.%2A.invocation_count,5)&from=-6h&until=now&format=json

Another one -
http://myGraphite/render/?width=586&height=308&target=mapSeries(server.%2A.route.root.admin.%2A.invocation_count,1)&from=-6h&until=now&format=json

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 109, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/render/views.py", line 125, in renderView
    seriesList = evaluateTarget(requestContext, target)
  File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/render/evaluator.py", line 10, in evaluateTarget
    result = evaluateTokens(requestContext, tokens)
  File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/render/evaluator.py", line 21, in evaluateTokens
    return evaluateTokens(requestContext, tokens.expression)
  File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/render/evaluator.py", line 27, in evaluateTokens
    func = SeriesFunctions[tokens.call.func]
KeyError: u'mapSeries'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that "mapSeries" is not available in the 0.9.x branch.
It is in the 0.10.x branch.

Comment: yes. mapSeries & reduceSeries were added in 1.0.0 and do not exist in 0.9.15 : http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releases/1_0_0.html#new-render-functions